# User id not coming in get_current_user_id() while running Custom endpoint post request

Tags: api, routes, endpoint, wordpress-rest-api, userid

I am getting this issue while using custom endpoints. My entire functionality is based on `get_current_user_id()`. So, when I am running endpoint url it's not working through custom endpoint.

Even in init function user id is null. But when I print anything it working fine on site.

I am using this:

```
             register_rest_route('v2', '/product/(?P\d+)/', 
                  array(
                       'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
                       'callback' => 'wp_get_webhook_product', 
                 ) 
             );
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.